# jQuery $.GET call, no data returned in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, cross-browser

Simple question. Perhaps already answered, but I couldn't find it (or in an understandable language). I have the following call:

```
$.get("php/send_reminder.php",{invoice_id:invoice_id},function(data){
      $("#send_reminder").val(data).attr("disabled","disabled");
})
```

In Opera and FireFox, #send_reminder is populated with the data returned. In Chrome, nothing. What is the trick for Chrome? (I'm using the latest Chrome in Linux Mint).

Thanks!

I found the culprit. Just before the above line I use window.open to open the mail client ("mailto:") with "_self" (to prevent a new window from popping up). Whereas browsers like Firefox and Opera seem to continue with the AJAX call, Chrome just cuts it off. En fin, thanks all and I will just have to figure another way to call the mail client.

Comment: try adding a semicolon after `})`

Comment: what console errors do you see?

Comment: What type of element is `#send_reminder`? A DIV, input, etc?

Comment: Side note - you may want to set the `disabled` property using `.prop("disabled", true)` for better consistency.  See: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but it is more about the data returned I am worried about. Should I use alert(data), I get a value in Opera and Firefox. In Chrome it is blank.

Answer (score 0):

2 things come to mind.  Make sure you're sending back HTML (set in the content header).  To make sure it's interpreted as such, add a parameter to the `get()` call.  Also, end with a semicolon.

```
$.get("php/send_reminder.php",{invoice_id:invoice_id},function(data){
      $("#send_reminder").val(data).attr("disabled","disabled");
}, "html");
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. I will try those suggestions and will report back as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, too. Solved it by doing the following:

```
$.get("php/send_reminder.php",{invoice_id:''+invoice_id},function(data){
  $("#send_reminder").val(data).attr("disabled","disabled"); 
});
```

Beware of the string concatenation in the parameters.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this as well and report back later.